# how to delete elements from this list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples `A` and list `B`.

Here I want to delete tuples if the first element of tuples is in the list `B`.

Here's the example:

```
A = [(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 9), (3, 8)]
B = [1, 2]

wanted_list = [(0, 2), (3, 8)]
```

I coded like below but it didn't work

```
for i in A:
    if i[0] in B:
        A.remove(i)
print(A)  # [(0, 2), (2, 9), (3, 8)]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```py
wanted_list = [item for item in A if item[0] not in B]
```

Comment: According to OP you only need to check the first tuple item, not all.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension and check if the first element is present in B

```
A = [(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 9), (3, 8)]
B = [1, 2]

C=[n for n in A if not n[0] in B]

print(C)
```

Comment: preferred syntax in python is `x not in y` and not `not x in y`

Comment: @StrangeSorcerer, I am used with the C# syntax that's why. Thanks anyways, I will try to correct myself in future :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.

```
C=[x for x in A if not any(b==x[0] for b in B)]
print(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new list and append the tuples  whose first item is not in the list B.

```
A = [(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 9), (3, 8)]
B = [1, 2]

lst = []

for i in A:
    if i[0] not in B:
        lst.append(i)

print(lst)
```